# How to take a link from one array and assign it to another?

Tags: reactjs

Friends, how to show the logo for the company from "arr1", the link to which is located in "arr2"? That is, to make the logo consistent with the company

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const arr1 = [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple"
      },
      {
        id: "random2",
        companyName: "Samsung"
      }
   ];

  const arr2 = [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple",
        logoUrl: "img.com/url"
      },
      {
        id: "random2",
        companyName: "Samsung",
        logoUrl: "img.com/url"
      }
   ];

  const blockCreate = () => {
    return arr1.map(item => {
      return (
        <p>
          <span>ID {item.id} - </span>
          <br />
          {item.companyName}
          <span>
            <br />
            <img src="#" />
          </span>
        </p>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

arr1 - Apple === arr2 - AppleLogo (logoUrl)

Now trying to do like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bush-zlyi6

Comment: why can't you use `arr2` directly? as the `id` and `companyName` both are available here? Why do you need diff array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`companyDetails` is your array so, do like this `arr2.companyDetails.find()`

Change this

```
  const blockCreate = (arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1.company.map(item => {
      const src = arr2.companyDetails.find(a => a.id === item.id).logoUrl;
      return (
        <p>
          <span>ID {item.id} - </span>
          <br />
          {item.companyName}
          <span>
            <br />
            <img src={src} alt="pic"/>
          </span>
        </p>
      );
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const arr1 = {
    company: [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple"
      },
      {
        id: "random2",
        companyName: "Samsung"
      }
    ]
  };

  const arr2 = {
    companyDetails: [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple",
        logoUrl: "img.com/url"
      },
      {
        id: "random2",
        companyName: "Samsung",
        logoUrl: "img.com/url"
      }
    ]
  };

  const blockCreate = (arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1.company.map(item => {
      const src = arr2.find(a => a.id === item.id).logoUrl;
      return (
        <p>
          <span>ID {item.id} - </span>
          <br />
          {item.companyName}
          <span>
            <br />
            <img src={src} />
          </span>
        </p>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate(arr1, arr2)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that I have passed `arr1` and `arr2` into the `blockCreate` function. This is better form than just having it access the variables on the higher scope since it makes your blockCreate function more modular, hence reusable.

Comment: arr2.find is not a function

Comment: @luckydev .find is standard ES6, which you appear to be using.

Comment: @seesharper the issue is not `find` function, the issue is, he named `arr1` and `arr2` but they are not actually an array but an object. He/you should've used `arr2.companyDetails.find` instead. But this is something he should've caught himself

Comment: @MatinKajabadi duh! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

As a react developer you should think about how this component can be re-usable meaning you can pass a single array of object and then have the component to always render the list of details.

The right way of doing this is to prepare the data before passing it to this component (can be handled in the backend or front-end depends on how you are getting this data). This is not the component's job to map through two different arrays and figure out the relation between those and render the list.

Here is an example in ECMAScript6:

```
  // Prepare the final data
  const hash = new Map();
  arr1.company.concat(arr2.companyDetails).forEach(obj => {
    hash.set(obj.id, Object.assign(hash.get(obj.id) || {}, obj));
  });

  const finalArray = Array.from(hash.values());

  const blockCreate = (finalArray) => {
   return arr3.map(item => {
     return (
      <p>
       <span>ID {item.id} - </span>
       <br />
       {item.companyName}
       <span>
        <br />
        <img src={item.logoUrl} alt="logo" />
       </span>
      </p>
     );
   });
  };
```